# C# Using .Contains on a RadComboboxItem searching for a string

Tags: c#, linq, telerik, type-conversion, radcombobox

Currently I am trying to create some cascading combo boxes.  The program has 4 RadComboBoxes (telerik control).  I place the default data into dropdowns and all is good.  I can multi-select from these boxes.  When I select values from box 1 it should filter the choices in box 2.

```
protected void rcbProgram_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        rcbPartGroup.DataSource = db.tblPartStyles.Where(c=>rcbProgram.CheckedItems.Contains(c.Program)).Select(c => c.PartGroup);
        rcbPartGroup.DataBind();

    }
```

I want rcbPartGroup's datasource to be the PartGroup field of tblPartStyles where the Program field is in rcbProgram's checked list.  This would work fine, but rcbProgram.CheckedList is a List and will not compare with a string (The program field value).  I am still having a difficult time wrapping my head around how this would work if both are strings, but now I have 2 different types that I cannot manage to convert.  Anyone have anything they know that I can do to make this work?

Comment: could you make a list of strings, then loop through the checked items, grabbing the strings you need and adding them to your new list? like a foreach(var item in rcbProgram.CheckedItems)

Comment: That is what I did.  it was more confusing to use the .Contains this way than it was difficult to come up with a solution.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit confused by the lambda statement at first.  I did a simple fix.  I created a list of strings and ran through a foreach to add the values in the CheckedItems list.  I then used the string list to perform the lambda filter.

```
 protected void rcbProgram_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        **List<String> _selectedItems = new List<String>();
        foreach (RadComboBoxItem i in rcbProgram.CheckedItems)
        {
            _selectedItems.Add(i.Value);
        }**


        rcbPartGroup.DataSource = db.tblPartStyles.Where(c=>_selectedItems.Contains(c.Program)).Select(c => c.PartGroup).Distinct();
        rcbPartGroup.DataBind();

    }
```